# Is there a package for topic diagnostics/message rate tracking and warning?

Tags: ros, messages, diagnostics, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in having something like a package with general nodes that subscribe to topics and publish warnings when messages aren't being sent or are coming in at the wrong rates and that publishes warnings when this happens.

I have a multi-robot system that suffers from a wide variety of often easily-mitigated errors related to things like hardware issues, wireless issues, etc. The biggest issue is generally detecting these errors. All of the typical failures involve streaming data such as heartbeats, odometry, and camera data. An easy way to track these streams in a separate node would be incredibly valuable. If someone has not already written a tool for this, I will likely write one myself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269188/is-there-a-package-for-topic-diagnostics/message-rate-tracking-and-warning?/) by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2017-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [wiki/arni](http://wiki.ros.org/arni).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) on 2017-08-21**:
Thanks. This looks a little more complex than what I was hoping for, but it looks like it can be configured to meet my needs.